# Google Sheets: Sum till particular date

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have time-series data that follows no predictable entries. For example as below.

| Date | Units |
| --- | --- |
| 01 Jan 2022 | 1 |
| 05 Jan 2022 | 2 |
| 08 Jan 2022 | 1 |
| 30 Jan 2022 | 1 |
| 04 Feb 2022 | 1 |
| 10 Feb 2022 | 1 |
| 13 Feb 2022 | 2 |
| 28 Feb 2022 | 1 |
| 07 Mar 2022 | 3 |
| 14 Mar 2022 | 1 |
| 23 Mar 2022 | 1 |
| 28 Mar 2022 | 3 |

What I want to do here is I want to add a sum to particular date. Expected output looks something below this.

| Date | Total Units till that date |
| --- | --- |
| 01 Jan 2022 | ? |
| 15 Jan 2022 | ? |
| 01 Feb 2022 | ? |
| 15 Feb 2022 | ? |
| 01 Mar 2022 | ? |
| 15 Mar 2022 | ? |

Now, I don't want to add all the dummy entries for missing dates in input table (because data is going to be huge)

Is there any way I can create a summary like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQ4CFfk0J0QjKLUmRYtQZms4Of9jaFDAeWNW56FeBF0/edit?usp=sharing

My solution works by using `SUMIF`. I'm not sure whether you want that day to be included in the count, but if you wanted to do so, just change the criterion to `"<=" & E2`.

Comment: This helped me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is my try, hope I understand you well
[image: Try]
[test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ozHnqnJF4P3RxOiRRdg801M5L_AdDB8YbVH_0JiN3c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Daniele. I didn't understand the point of the table on the right side. Why is it required? Can we skip it?

Comment: That column (the Z) is used to automatically calculate 15-day periods (mid-month and end of month) so that you don't have to think about updating column C ... the update will happen automatically... BTW you can place that calculazion in another column, if you prefer